# How to do google search without getting captcha

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping

I have this vba script which performs about 60 to 80 searches on google.com but I am getting captcha after some queries I understand its a violation of google terms of use. Is there any way I can resolve this issue?

Can custom google search https://cse.google.com/cse/ help me in any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few of ways..

1. Both Google and Bing offer CSE - But they have limitations on how many query per day/per month. But that can be increased with paid options.
2. The more IP's you have the more you can "Search" before getting a captcha block
3. You can purchase a BackConnect Rotating Proxy - The IP's on these proxies change every 10 mins - This enables you to search more.
4. You can purchase/code Captcha solving Software, that will solve the Captcha for you.

Those are you options, obviously the correct way is #1 and then you start to go into the shades of grey.